# C - Determining alphabetical order of characters/strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to write a function that compares two strings (s1 and s2) and works out whether s1 comes before, after or is equal to the s2 string, alphabetically (in the same way as a dictionary is read). If s1 comes before s2 it should return -1. If it's equal to s2 it should return 0. If it comes after s2 it should return 1.

I'm having difficulty getting the function to work - I can only seem to get returns for the first chars in each string and only using the same case.  Grateful for any help you can give.

Here's the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpstr(const char *, const char *);

int main()
{
    printf("Test 1: %d\n", cmpstr( "Hello", "World"));
    printf("Test 2: %d\n", cmpstr( "Hello", "Hello"));
    printf("Test 3: %d\n", cmpstr( "World", "Hello"));

    return 0;
}


int cmpstr(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{

    /*compare corresponding string characters until null is reached*/
    while(*s1 != '\0'  && *s2 != '\0' )
    {
        if (*s1 < *s2)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (*s1 > *s2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
            s1++;
            s2++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `strcmp` not an option?

Comment: `strcmp` is comparing lexicographically indeed. You might want to convert everything to lowercase though...

Comment: Get rid of the `return 0` from inside the loop.  It makes no sense, and the code that follows is uneachable (i.e., dead code).  As it is, you are *always* returning on the first iteration, never incremementing `s1` or `s2`, and never looking at more than one character.  You also need to add logic to handle the case where the strings are not the same length.

Comment: Move `s1++; s2++;` out of that code block. They are never executed.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, the incremenents are fine where they are.  The return before them is the problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes true, but all those `else`s are obfuscation, since the previous code never reaches them.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, yes, they certainly aren't needed.  But they're not directly causing the bugs.

Comment: what if `s1` is shorter than `s2` or vice versa?

Comment: @DeiDei - No I need to do it using pointer arithmetic only.

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Removing 'return 0' in else statement will work. If the chars are equal in same level, you need to look next ones until the equality breaks.

Edit: Also, you need to think about when lengths of strings are not equal.

```
int cmpstrMY(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char sc1, sc2;
    /*compare corresponding string characters until null is reached*/
    while (1)
    {
        sc1 = towlower(*s1);
        sc2 = towlower(*s2);

        if (sc1 == '\0'  && sc2 == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        else if (sc1 == '\0' && sc2 != '\0') {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (sc1 != '\0' && sc2 == '\0') {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (sc1 < sc2)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (sc1 > sc2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            s1++;
            s2++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your cmpstr must be something like the code above.

Comment: Tom is right, and I modified your code in this direction.

Comment: Duygu - Firstly, thank you (and others) for your help.  I'm just wondering if it would be ok to use `tolower` instead of `towlower`? I don't fully understand the difference between wide and narrow characters.

Comment: Hello somers! It is okay to use "tolower" instead of "towlower", it shouldn't effect how the code works. I used it because of the habit.  Wide character has increased datatype size to store larger coded character sets. In this example it is unnecessary to use.

Comment: Duygu - Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the last else part and put return 0 out of loop because both string are only equal if  **if part** and **else-if part** will not be true, when it will come out from loop it will return 0.

```
int cmpstr(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{

        /*compare corresponding string characters until null is reached*/
        while(*s1 != '\0'  && *s2 != '\0' )
        {
                if (*s1 < *s2)
                {
                        return -1;
                }
                else if (*s1 > *s2)
                {
                        return 1;
                }
                s1++;
                s2++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a very obvious mistake, which is the `return 0`-statement making the `s1++;s2++` to unreachable code (your compiler should have warned you about that).

But it has also a conceptual mistake, as it ignores situations where `s1` is longer than `s2` or vice versa. So in your approach (once corrected the `return 0`-thing, `"Hello"` and `"Hello there"` would compare equal.

See the following code with works in a different manner. It skips equal characters until one (or both) strings has (have) ended. Then, according to this state, result is determined:

```
int cmpstr(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 && *s2 && *s1 == *s2) { // move forward until either one of the strings ends or the first difference is detected.
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    int result = (*s1 - *s2);
    // if both strings are equal, s1 and s2 have reached their ends and result is 0
    // if *s1 > *s2, s1 is lexographically greater than s2 and result is positive
    // if *s1 < *s2, s1 is lexographically lower than s2 and result is negative

    // normalize "positive" and "negative" to 1 and -1, respectively
    if (result < 0)
        result = -1;
    else if (result > 0)
        result = 1;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Stephan Lechner - I've tried to modify your code to include upper and lower case characters but I can't get it working properly, it's only giving returns of 1.  I've included the code as an edit in my post.